# Asus computer gets stuck at “Checking for Updates”

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

When I try to startup this computer, it won’t go past Checking For Updates. I’m pretty sure it’s Windows 8.1 but this computer was given to me from a family member. I can’t go to files or anything because I can’t get past creating a profile for my computer. Does anyone know how to fix this? I’ve tried restarting my computer but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Turn off the laptop.
2. Turn off your WiFi, or take the laptop to an area where there isn't any WiFi. (If connected via Ethernet, unplug it.)
3. Turn on the laptop.
4. Once it fully loads, then turn on your WiFi again.

It should work now. Sometimes (especially in 10) updates, including those that come after a reset, can get the computer stuck. It happens when an update fails, for whatever reason, and the device continually tries to get it to install over and over. Leaving you 'stuck'. Until you take away its ability to continue trying the update, hence the no WiFi, then it should load.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!

Comment: @Maddelin Rogers my pleasure :)